# Embedded Facebook group feed not showing personal data

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I am trying to fetch a simple feed from a Facebook group, to render on a web page.

From what I understand, I need to use the Group API, and this requires an app that is submitted for review.

What I'm struggling with is that the review process requires me to submit a screen cast of the feed working, but I need the review to *get* the feed working.

With a user access token (as opposed to an app token which I suppose I will be using after review approval) I can get results from the API, but I am still unable to load any user data (ie the `from` field is not populated). I don't see how I can meet the prerequisites to the app review without first being approved.

Am I missing a permission or looking at the wrong fields, or something else entirely?

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#groups-4-4 you can not get the `from` field any more for posts from the /group/feed edge.

Comment: _“(as opposed to an app token which I suppose I will be using after review approval)”_ - nope, you can’t access a group feed via an app token; this has nothing to do with reviewed or not.

Comment: @misorude: I haven't been able to discern it from the docs - any advice on how to get said data? Or is the simple scenario of rendering a feed of posts together with the name of the poster no longer achievable?